# Cast pointer to variable on creation

Tags: c++

Today I saw a strange initialization of a pointer. It looks like this:

```
struct A
{
  void* data;
  int bufLen;
  ...
}

void fun(A* a, int* result)
{
  SomeClass* b = new (a->data) SomeClass();
}
```

It's completely fine, it does compile, it does work, but I don't know why.
I'd like to know what's going on with the initialization of the variable `b`.
Is it a cast? Is it a copy of the variable `a->data` in a new memory slot?

Comment: It's called [placement `new`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What uses are there for "placement new"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Comment: Thank you @Biffen. One question: for example, can I use the `SomeClass` variable to pass information to another thread? If I can, do I need anyway to call the descrutor in the `fun` function?

Comment: **1** Yes. **2** It depends. This has nothing to do with placement `new`, though.

Comment: In the webpage you linked it says that I need to call explicitly the destructor in this case. My first thought was that if I deallocate that specific part of memory then this means that it can be used for other purpose. But I need to read that part of memory from another thread before it can be used again by some else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *placement new* and it's generally used to place an object in a specified address in memory.

In your code, an object of type `SomeClass` will be placed at the memory location of `a->data`.

To use it, you can overload the `operator new` by yourself, or use the ones already defined in the Standard Library, contained in the header file `<new>`.